# Future-proofing access to packed array tools

Tags: packages, contexts, packed-arrays

Most of the Mathematica users beyond beginner level will be aware of the phenomenon of *Packed Arrays*. The user-accessible functions related to packed arrays live in the `` Developer` ``context and have been there for quite some time. I wonder what this means for their future use.

Is `` Developer` `` more stable than `` Experimental` ``? Can we expect this functionality to move into the kernel and what calling strategies could we adopt to minimize the effects such a move would have?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think that `` Developer` `` is going to go away; there is too much (also internal) stuff depending on it. What I do at the beginning of a package:

```
pack = Developer`ToPackedArray;
packedQ = Developer`PackedArrayQ;
```

then only use those; if anything changes then it's only one place I need to change it. On the other hand a re-factoring: of `` Developer`ToPackagedArray `` is not the end of the world.

Concerning moving this to the kernel: unlikely. It has not been done in the past (for probably good reasons), why should it happen now. I don't think there is generally a way to classify stability of packages; if it is in the kernel, it is more stable than if it is in a package that you have to explicitly load.

Comment: What would be nice if the Developer` package would get loaded by default. Then it would not matter if people type Developer`ToPackedArray or ToPackedArray. Just like JLink` these days (which did not load by default on startup until Mathematica 6).

Comment: @RolfMertig, I'll mention that, but I have a feeling that this is not going to happen.